# Use putExtra with int (Android)

Tags: android

I'm developing a calendar :

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final int EXTRA_DAY = 0;
private final int EXTRA_MONTH = 0;
private final int EXTRA_YEAR= 0;

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddEvent.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DAY, currentItem.day);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MONTH, currentItem.month);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_YEAR, currentItem.year);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

} }
```

I have this error : "Cannot resolve this method 'putExtra(int, int)'.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `putExtra` method will always have a `String` as 1st parameter.

There is the list of all the methods available:
[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))

Answer (score 0):

You should understand how the method putExtra() works.

If you check out the [Intent Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)), You will notice that the putExtra() function takes a `String` as it's first parameter, which refers to the name of the extra, and some data type(e.g. String,boolean,Byte[] etc.) as it's second parameter. For example:

```
String name = "Some text";
int dayOfYear = 5;

public void intent(){
    Intent someIntent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
    someIntent.putExtra("myname", name);
    someIntent.putExtra("today",dayOfYear);
    startActivity(someIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exchange it with this:

```
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_DAY", currentItem.day);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MONTH", currentItem.month);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_YEAR", currentItem.year);
```

Later when you want to read the data in the intent, use

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int day = i.getIntExtra("EXTRA_DAY");
int month = i.getIntExtra("EXTRA_MONTH");
int year = i.getIntExtra("EXTRA_YEAR");
```